# Rewrite Regex to to be used in comparing?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i rewrite this regex?

```
var exp = /(070|071|072|073|074|075|076|077|078|079)\d{7,8}$/;
```

can i do this;

```
var exp[] = {070,071,072,073,074,075,076,077,078,079};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest change would be to use:

```
var exp = /(07\d)\d{7,8}$/;
```

instead of listing out each of the ten consecutive digits.